# c# combobox in form opened in panel

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I got problem with `ComboBox` in winforms c#. Comboboxes in main window works fine, but comboboxes in form that I open in panel on main window are broken.  The wierd things starts to happen... I cant click it to type. I can only open list, select one and then type. Also i cant locate cursor in the middle of text because it highlight whole text. I post code with I open form in panel:

```
public void otworzOkno(Form _form)
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[_form.Name] != null)
    {
        Application.OpenForms[_form.Name].WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Application.OpenForms[_form.Name].BringToFront();
    }
    else
    {
        _form.TopLevel = false; 
        _form.AutoScroll = true;
        this.panel.Controls.Add(_form);
        _form.Show();
        _form.BringToFront();
    }      
}
```

Video that will explain problem: https://youtu.be/PrVxFWvhPyc

Comment: "Are broken"? What is that supposed to mean? And why are you using Application.OpenForms (haven't ever seen such an approach and have used Winforms a lot)?. Could you please explain what you want, what you tried and what problem do you have? (i.e., a clear description and/or error message; by trying to avoid statements like "it doesn't work" or "is broken" or similar) You should be able to access any control without any problem by bearing mind the given container (i.e., if you include a control in a panel, the container would be that panel rather than the main form).

Comment: I got main form with menu and panel. When I click on buttons I open new forms in panel. The form opened in panel got some problem with combobox. I cant click it to write a text. When i open dropdown list and choose item for exapmle 'ac' i cant click in middle to write 'abc' because it highlights whole text. The biggest problem is with writting in it. I discovered thats because form is opened in panel, when i open it 'normally' as seperate form it works fine.

Comment: Let's go step by step. The basic control in winforms is the form, not the panel. That is: firstly you have a form and, inside it, you can have a panel or 1000 or anything other thing, but not the way around! Each form is basically a window.

Comment: Maybe i post a video on youtube. We probably misunderstanding because of my poor english. Ill record and post it in few seconds

Comment: A video?! No, don't do that. The point of asking here is not asking me, but writing down clear ideas which might be understood by anyone (now and in the future). And SO is not for learning basics. If you are not sure about how to use this site you should take a look at the help pages. You should try to do all the learning by your own (asking is a bad way to learn). Sorry I will not help more here (2-3 comments is OK, but nothing beyond that). PS: note that we are in "special days" and that's why your question has been upvoted, but don't get used to this (usually, it would have been downvoted).

Answer (score 0):

Without further info, there's not much we can do but i'll try my best.
First, to have a form inside a form you must use MDI (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76(v=vs.110).aspx). If you're not, stop here and fix it...
Second, in a MDI app, setting up events can get messy, especially when you're trying to have a outer-form feedback a inner form... check that!
Third, in order to better understand whats going on, try subscribing to events such as `Focus`, and inspecting who else is listening... maybe someone is overriding a event and you don't realised it...